# procedure NEW causes segmentation fault

Tags: delphi, dynamic, pascal, freepascal

So i'm trying to implement a C-style stack structure in fpc
the main principle is: each element has a value and a pointer to the next element, the stack itself only contains a pointer to the last element of it

```pascal
type stackNode = class
public
    val: integer;
    next: ^stackNode;
end;

type stack = class
private
    top: ^stackNode;
public
    constructor Create();
    procedure push(v: integer);
    procedure clear();
    function pop():integer;
    function back():integer;
    destructor Destroy();
end;
```

here's how I implemented `push` in C++:

```cpp
void push(_t _v) {
    top = new stackNode<_t>(_v, top);
}
```

however, when i'm trying to implement basically the same piece of code in pascal

```pascal
procedure stack.push(v: integer);
var
    temp: ^stackNode;
begin
    temp := top;
    new(top);
    top^.next := temp;
    top^.val := v;
end;
```

it gives me a segmentation fault after calling `new()` when i'm trying to push the second element into the stack.
something's telling me that pascal's `new()` doesn't *really* allocate memory dynamically.

Is **dynamic** memory allocation even possible in pascal?

Comment: If the code you are copying from is a generic, why don't you implement it as a generic in FPC ?

Comment: "Is dynamic memory allocation even possible in Pascal? Of course it is. Why would you suspect that Pascal is the problem here? Usually when our code doesn't work its because our code is wrong.

Answer (score 6):

`stackNode` is a `class`, not a `record`.  A class is a reference type, so declaring a variable of a `class` type is actually declaring a pointer to an object of that type.  Thus, do not use `^` to add an *additional* layer of indirection to that variable.  `New()` allocates memory for the *dereferenced* type of the pointer that is passed to it, so by declaring `top` as `^stackNode`, ie a pointer to a pointer to a `stackNode` object, you are telling `New()` to allocate memory only for a `stackNode` pointer, not for an actual `stackNode` object.

More importantly, an object of a `class` type needs to be created by calling a constructor of the class, not using `New()`, which will just allocate raw memory without calling any constructor on it.  Conversely, objects of `class` types need to be destroyd by calling their destructor, not `Dispose()`.

Try this instead:

```pascal
type
  stackNode = class
  public
    val: integer;
    next: stackNode;
  end;

  stack = class
  private
    top: stackNode;
  public
    constructor Create;
    destructor Destroy; override;
    procedure push(v: integer);
    ...
  end;

...

constructor stack.Create;
begin
  inherited;
  ...
end;

destructor stack.Destroy;
var
  temp, next: stackNode;
begin
  temp := top;
  while temp <> nil do
  begin
    next := temp;
    temp.Free;
    temp := next;
  end;
  inherited;
end;

procedure stack.push(v: integer);
var
  temp: stackNode;
begin
  temp := top;
  top := stackNode.Create;
  top.next := temp;
  top.val := v;
end;
```

That being said, I would suggest adding a constructor to `stackNode` to take the required member values as input, eg:

```pascal
type
  stackNode = class
  public
    val: integer;
    next: stackNode;
    constructor Create(AValue: Integer; ANext: stackNode = nil);
  end;

...

constructor stackNode.Create(AValue: Integer; ANext: stackNode = nil);
begin
  inherited Create;
  val := AValue;
  next := ANext;
end;
```

That way, `push()` can be simplified to this:

```pascal
procedure stack.push(v: integer);
begin
  top := stackNode.Create(v, top);
end;
```

Answer (score 1):

`top` is a class, so you need to call its constructor, instead of `New()`'ing it like a record.